# How to horizontally align using css when the size is based on page width

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have two separate text elements that need to be aligned and are sized proportional to the screen width (using vw). I use vw to align them vertically and that works but aligning them horizontally using vh moves them out of alignment when the page size is changed.

Is there a way of getting around this?

```
#titleone {
font-size: 9vw;
position: absolute;
right: 53.8vw;
top: 25vh;
z-index: 3;
}

#titletwo {
font-size: 4.5vw;
position: absolute;
right: 38.7vw;
top: 25vh;
z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your question with some codes or demo?

Comment: Okay, do  you need anything else?

Comment: It would be nice if you can create a minimal, concrete and verifiable example, and describe explicitly the desired behaviour. An image would also help—if you have issues with embedding images, just paste the URL and I can help you to insert it into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
calc(25vh + 5vw);
```

The error from the font size is taken into account when resizing